# Classification in real time without prior knowledge of the number of classes

Tags: r, classification, python, real-time

Is there an implemented algorithm (with python/R or java in preference) that can classify incoming data from an unknown generator with absolutely no prior knowledge or assumption.

**For example:**

Let G be a generator of 2d vectors that generate one vector in each second.

What we know, and nothing else, is that this vectors are separable into **clusters** in space (euclidean distance).

Question: How can I classify my data in real time so that at each iteration, the algorithm propose clusters?

Comment: Are you asking about [cluster analyses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis)? To classify, you have to know what the classes are.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I know about clustering, The problem here that I don't have the number of clusters.

Comment: So is it that you want to cluster data where you don't know the right number of clusters in advance?

Comment: @gung yes that's my problem

Comment: Current voting suggests this question may be too vague and too broad to be answerable. Perhaps you could edit the post to provide more information about the data and the purposes of the classification.

Comment: Thanks--it's getting clearer.  It could help further to explain what measure of distance or similarity you intend to use for the clustering. It's not always just Euclidean distance!  You should also indicate whether you want this clustering itself to be performed in real time ("online"), or whether you can cache all the data and perform the clustering procedure later. The two problems are different in some profound ways.

Comment: @whuber yes of course, thanks and sorry for the lack of clarity

Comment: Either you need to be more application specific or you are trying to screw a square peg in a round hole.
What do you mean by real time classification? Do you have latency constraints or you are refering to the classification of stream data?
If you have stream datasource are the observations evolving or do you work with differnt instances over time? (like a service)

Comment: @Ramalho I look for an answer for the simple case described above (geometric classification with euclidean distance )

Answer (score 1):

DBSCAN seems to suit your purpose, it doesnt need a fixed number of clusters and will surely find correct clusters in the separable clusters case.
If instances where not random but actually drifting between time instances (like moving points) i would give incremental DBSCAN a try.

DBSCAN is available in either of the languages you mentioned.

Regarding the temporal "dimension" of the problem you accumulate instances and after a certain criteria is met (minimum number of instances, time window size) you cluster the accumulated observations and repeat.

Comment: The problem is that DBSCAN don't works with clusters with different density (it's a very strong assumption in my case)

Comment: It will work for the specific case of clusters being well separated. Tough if dbscan really doesn't work you may try OPTICS.